# Automatically link function names to api.drupal.org

Tags: feature-request, links

Is it possible to automatically turn core function names into links to api.drupal.org? For instance: 'hook_node_load' would become '[hook_node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_load)'.

If it's possible at all, would you consider it helpful?

We would at least need figure out how to handle common words that match function names by coincidence. For instance, we don't need to link 'theme' to http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7 everywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/319/markdown-for-drupal-api-reference

Comment: Sorry I didn't find that one before I posted this. It's not an exact duplicate, but definitely related.

Comment: Yea, just thought would be worth showing both for the sake of discussion

Answer (score 3):

This is a good idea, although an existing JavaScript library that parses function names would be a stronger selling point to Stack Exchange. [Other Stack Exchange sites already use the MathJax library](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-partners-with-mathjax/).

I think the generic name for Drupal function use case can be solved by always referring to functions as (for example) `theme()` or `hook_node_load()`.

Comment: You're right, the brackets should be enough to differentiate between a word and a function name. Using an existing library is always a good idea, but I wouldn't know which library.